# Loading nested dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7

Environment is Python 2.7, external library backports csv module.

So i have a csv file with information and i am trying to load it into a very specific format for ease of access.

[image]

Now the desired format is:

[image]

The "primary" key being the city name and then having two nested dictionary elements. One for credentials (username and password, both key's) and finally one for lists where each list which belongs to that city is added. So some cities would have more lists than others as you can see in the screenshot below.

My code attempt to try and accomplish this is:

```
from backports import csv
import json
import string
import datetime
import hmac
import base64
import hashlib
import requests
import pprint
import time
from io import open

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib

def get_data(file_name):
  header_list = ""
  with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    try:
      # Python 2's next call
      header_list = reader.next()
    except AttributeError:
      # Python 3.0 and later
      header_list = next(reader)
    data = [row for row in reader]
  return data

csv_file = "mapping.csv"
csv_data = get_data(csv_file)
print(len(csv_data))

credentials = dict()
cities = dict()
for x in csv_data:
  lists = dict()
  credentials.update([('username', str(x[2])), ('password', str(x[3]))])

  list_name = x[0]
  list_id = x[4]

  try:
    lists = cities[key]['lists']
  except:
    pass

  lists[list_name] = list_id

  key = x[1]
  value = {'credentials': credentials, 'lists': lists}
  cities.update([(key, value)])

print("")
print(cities)
```

**The Issue:**
I am having a really hard time with this because it's added ALL of the list_names to every single city_id, regardless if it's for that one or not. any help would be appreciated. I'm at the point where i'm not sure why what i'm trying to do is flawed. Thanks.

**Current Result:**

```
newyork
{'credentials': {'username': 'exotic', 'password': 'abc123'}, 'lists': {u'a': u'9', u'c': u'8', u'b': u'10'}}
miami
{'credentials': {'username': 'exotic', 'password': 'abc123'}, 'lists': {u'a': u'9', u'c': u'8', u'b': u'10'}}
washington
{'credentials': {'username': 'exotic', 'password': 'abc123'}, 'lists': {u'a': u'9', u'c': u'8', u'b': u'10'}}
detroit
{'credentials': {'username': 'exotic', 'password': 'abc123'}, 'lists': {u'a': u'9', u'c': u'8', u'b': u'10'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i realized my own mistake, went over it again. I was doing the assignments inside of the loop completely wrong. For anyone that's interested here is the correct code.

```
for x in csv_data:
  city = x[1]

  try:
    mycity = cities[city]
  except:
    cities[city] = {}

  try:
    lists = cities[city]['lists']
  except:
    cities[city]['lists'] = {}

  list_name = x[0]
  list_id = x[4]

  cities[city]['lists'][list_name] = list_id

  try:
    credentials = cities[city]['credentials']
  except:
    cities[city]['credentials'] = {}

  username = x[2]
  password = x[3]

  cities[city]['credentials']['username'] = username
  cities[city]['credentials']['password'] = password
```

Basically, i had to check if a key already existed, if it didn't, i needed to create it and assign an empty value to it.